# Permutations of a list - Python

Tags: python

Given a list with n letters, like `['a','b','c']`, output the different combinations. For this example, the output would be `['abc','acb','bac','bca','cab','cba']`. Although I have solved this problem, unfortunately it is very inefficient, when the number of elements is a little larger, like 10, the code does not work with memory error. Does anyone have a fast and efficient algorithm to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are permutations, not combinations.

`itertools` has what you need:

```
from itertools import permutations

[''.join(perm) for perm in permutations(li)]
```

The docs for [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) have a few more recipes.